# run multiple instances of JBoss 4 in a one single machine?

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.0.x

I need to run multiple instances of jboss in a single machine (more than 5).

I copied the entire jboss folder several times and used the -b parameter on startup.

Under jboss/server, I have the following:

```
default
instance1
instance2
```

The first instance of jboss works fine (when I run `./run.sh -c instance1 -b 1.1.1.1`)

but when I start the second one (when I run `./run.sh -c instance2 -b 1.1.1.2`), it hangs on

```
[Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are you binding to different ports?

Comment: Even if I try to bind different ports, I get the same problem